# tomcat 7 to 9 migration :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified […] is not valid

Tags: java, tomcat

We are trying to migrating from Tomcat7 to Tomcat9, while deploying war file we are seeing below exception, the same war is working fine in tomcat7.
Here we are using openJDK11.
This is the catalina error log I am getting while trying to start the server:

```
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@cb0755b]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4758)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4893)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:972)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:695)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:706)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 41 more

06-Dec-2018 05:24:44.961 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor []
```

**server.xml**

```xml
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
              unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

            <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
                 Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
            <!--
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
            -->

            <!-- Access log processes all example.
                 Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
                 Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                   prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
                   pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>

        </Host>
```

please let me know needs anymore details.

Comment: Do you have a `ROOT.xml` file in `.../conf/Catalina/localhost`? If the `<Context>` element has a `path` attribute, remove the attribute.

Comment: Yes I have, removed but still seeing same error

Comment: can anyone please help us ?